# Django summary query

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible in Django to write a query for related models that presents a summary grouped by location, with the object count and the number of related objects?

For example:

with Models

```
class Job(models.Model):
    id_number = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()

class Item(models.Model):
    id_number = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

If I wanted to get an admin.model that groups the jobs by location and shows the total count of items for each location

```
| Location | Number of Jobs | Number of Items |
-----------------------------------------------
| Chicago  |      52        |      305       |
| Seattle  |      12        |      185       |
```

etc,.

I've tried with aggregation and annotation queries, but these always seem to only work with one of the counted columns being accurate or the locations aren't grouped /are split. I feel like this should be simple in Django, but the ORM is breaking by brain...

I've tried an admin.model like below, but this splits up the location...

```
@admin.register(JobSummary)
class JobSummaryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("location", "job_count", "item_count")

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)

        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _job_count=Count("id",  distinct=True),
            _item_count=Count("item", distinct=True),
        )
        return queryset

    def job_count(self, obj):
        return obj._job_count

    def item_count(self, obj):
        return obj._item_count
```

Thanks for any advice

Han

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregations only work over natural querysets. Since your location field is free-form CharField, you can't build a queryset around it. What you must first do is break the Location out into it's own model.

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Job(models.Model):
    id_number = models.CharField()
    models.ForeignKey(Location)

class Item(models.Model):
    id_number = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job)
```

Then you can make a query for the Location that annotates with new fields

```
@admin.register(Location)
class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "job_count", "item_count")

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)

        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _job_count=Count("job_set", distinct=True),
            _item_count=Count("job_set__item_set", distinct=True),
        )
        return queryset

    def job_count(self, obj):
        return obj._job_count

    def item_count(self, obj):
        return obj._item_count
```

Comment: Wow. super fast.  Exactly what I needed.Thanks so much Thomas.